# Windows 64 bit application with ever growing thread count

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++, usb

I have a Windows 64 C++ application which acquires data from a custom USB device. It is built using Qt 4.8.

It works fine and there are no , repeat no memory leaks that I can see. However, I did notice , with some alarm, an ever growing thread count. Using process explorer in debug  I can see multiple calls to MSVCR90D.dllbeginthreadex. However, I cannot find where in the application this happens. It is the same for a release build. I would have thought that every new thread would take up the default stack size and show up as every increasing private bytes but there is no evidence of this.

I have checked the driver extensively and it seems not to be the cause. The endpoints are only created once with a _beginthread call and not after connection.

Is there anyway of finding out what causes this?

Comment: Use a debugger.  Debug + Windows + Threads window in Visual Studio.  Hover over one of those threads to see what it is doing.  If they look like they got started by the USB driver, likely, then you'll need support from the vendor.

Comment: They are terminating at the same rate that they are being created?

Comment: No, they never terminate. We are the USB vendor.

Comment: No threads showing up in the Debug+Windows+Threads window at all which is expected behaviour as the app doesn't create any at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much to my annoyance the answer was staring at me. In process explorer, I didn't realise that you could look at the call stack for thread entries. I could see the call originated from qt_plugin_query_verification_data. I then found that a Phonon resource was constantly calling back with a new thread each time and as it never got answered the thread stayed. I tracked it down to a very silly , seemingly simple problem of playing audio cues to the user.

Rearranging the phonon play code got rid of the problem. Thanks for the suggestions though. I have learnt a lot today.

Added:

Lessons learnt:

- Process explorer is a wonderful tool in oh so many ways. It's worth
  while spending some time learning it's powers.
- Read vendor example code carefully and fully understand. Write small examples for api calls and test carefully.
- Runaway thread creation with no corresponding increase in the stack size suggests a lightweight signalling problem.